# django and database connection pools when connecting to many databases

Tags: django

If I want my application to connect to potentially hundreds of different databases, what effect will this have on database pools?

I'm assuming django has database connection pooling, and if I am connection to 1000 different databases, that will result in allot of memory used up in connection pools no?

Answer (score 1):

Django does not have database connection pooling, it leaves this up to other tools for that purpose (for example pg-bouncer or pg-pool for PostgreSQL). So there is no worry with the number of database you're connecting to in terms of keeping those connections open and using up a bunch of RAM.